# Run Java EE Application client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3

How to run a Java EE desktop application client outside Netbeans?

If I double click `jar`, it says "java exception". All (client, `ejb` and `web`) modules are deployed, and `glassfish` and desktop client `jar` are on same machine (Windows).

I've follwed this tut http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/devguide/html/Client3.html

and when I run `runclient -client ConverterApp.ear -name MyConverterClient` in `cmd` it says runclient unknown command.

Comment: The tutorial you're following is of J2EE 1.2.1 dating from 2000. I don't think that is the right version, unless you're stuck on a legacy codebase. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) is probably what you should be following.

Comment: Yes its glassfish 3 and netbeans 7.1. In that link there is no "run desktop application client" section?

Comment: Did you check [this NB tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html) ?

Comment: Did you read "How to run JEE desktop application client outside Netbeans?" in my first post?

Comment: What is stopping you from figuring out the command that Netbeans uses to run the client? All you need are some JARs in the classpath.

Comment: There is no "hacking" involved. Netbeans fires the Application Client Container through a java task in an ant script. If you had used searched well enough, you would have found [the documentation outlining it's usage in the Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakt.html). The documentation is comprehensive enough - it outlines what jars you possibly need, and also documents 1. the appclient script to be used when want to launch the ACC 2. the package-appclient script to be used when you want to run without a GF installation. Maybe you're just lazy.

Answer (score 2):

Java application can be executed using java virtual machine as following:

`java -cp yourjar.jar` YourMainClass`

If your main class belongs to package you should write something like the following:

`java -cp yourjar.jar` com.mycompany.YourMainClass`

I hope this helps although I do not really understand what does "Java EE desktop application client" mean. I hope this a a kind of java application that connects to your Java EE backend.

Comment: If it is an executable jar (which is likely since there will probably be all kinds of dependency jars that need to be on the classpath), you actually execute java -jar yourjar.jar

Comment: Thats for JSE jar. I'm talking about JEE desktop application client module jar.